# parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')'

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i trie to change title page use

```
@section('page_title', {{  $mapel->subjects_name  }} )
```

but view error message

> syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')' (View:
> /mnt/187621C87621A788/ProjekWeb/eLearning/resources/views/lesson/index.blade.php)

in my controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    $mapel = Subjects::findOrFail($id);
    return view('lesson.index', compact('mapel'));
}
```

I've tried to check with dd($mapel->subjects_name) and the data comes out, thank u

Comment: change to `@section('page_title', $mapel->subjects_name)` you don't need to parse blade syntax inside the blage directives [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you need to compact it, I think you can directly send $mapel like

```
return view('lesson.index', $mapel);
```

then in view

```
@section('page_title', $mapel->subjects_name );
```

or

```
@section('page_title', ['mapel_subject_name' => $mapel->subjects_name] )
```

whatever you prefer.